# Why my app crash when clickong on the button?

Tags: xamarin, button, crash

My App crash when I click the button. I use visual studio for my xamarin project for a Wake on lan app. When i create the Cliked method in the xaml it creates automatically the clicked method on the code behind bbut when i instal it on my device it crash when i clicked on it. It doesn't if i put no code in the method. But i don't know if it because of the click method or the method i call when i click on it.

It doesn't when i put no code in the clicked method.

This is the xaml :

```
<Button Text="Allumer" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
```

This is the code behind :

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       WOL.wakeUp();
    }
```

And this is the code for the method wakeUp :

```
public static void wakeUp()
    {
        var client = new UdpClient();
        client.Connect(IPAddress.Broadcast, 9); 
        byte[] mac = new byte[] { 0x1C, 0x6F, 0x65, 0xC5, 0x9E, 0x68 };
        byte[] packet = new byte[17 * 6];

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            packet[i] = 0xFF;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                packet[i * 6 + j] = mac[j];
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(packet);

        client.Send(packet, packet.Length);
    }
```

Comment: Have you attempted to debug it?  Either step through the code in the debugger, or capture the exception using try/catch?

Comment: Since we couldn't see the full code , so, you should debug your code step by step and found the error.